# Dial up Free Service Usable In France?

Tags: dialup

Ok this has been bugging me for a while. I am looking for one of the free ISP services where you just dial a local rate number for internet access.

I have a requirement for someone to use a dial up laptop in France on an adhoc basis so cannot sign up to a broadband package and are often in the middle of no where, with no wifi or broadband available.

I am looking for an equivalent of the 0845 ISPs where you just have the number and a standard username and pass.

Anyone know of any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [free dialup service](http://subscribe.free.fr/accesgratuit/index.html) of Free.

You should also consider 3G :-)

Comment: Also if you subscribe to Free you get access to their community Wifi, and can connect through any of their subscribers' modem (provided they didn't disable wifi or declined the feature). Note that you're on a separate address through a VPN, you obviously don't see the users' local network.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://subscribe.free.fr/accesgratuit/index.html.